# Getting API Data within Swift

Tags: json, swift, coinmarketcap

I'm trying to get some data from an API at the address https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/?convert=AUD

I've started a new playground within Xcode, and my code is as follows

```
let urlString = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/?convert=AUD"

let url = URL(string: urlString)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error as Any)
    } else {
        do {
            
            let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]
            let id = parsedData["id"] as! [String:Any]
            
            print(id)
            
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    }.resume()
```

However the playground is returning no result. I am quite new to Swift, so some of the syntax may be a little off. Can anyone make a suggestion how to obtain the information obtained at the API address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import PlaygroundSupport and set needsIndefiniteExecution to true.
Also you have some errors in the code as the result is array and you are casting it into a dictionary [String : Any].
Use the following code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let urlString = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/?convert=AUD"

let url = URL(string: urlString)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        do {

            let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [[String : Any]]
            for item in parsedData
            {
                let id = item["id"] as! String
                print(id)
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    }.resume()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
extension ViewController {
func getApi() {
    
    let url = URL(string: getApiUrl)!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            
            print(error)
        } else if let data = data {
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let response = try decoder.decode(Birthday.self, from: data)
                print(response)
                 print(response.name)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    self.getApiUrl = response
                    
                }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            
        } else {
            print("something went wrong")
        }
    }
    
    task.resume()
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
extension ViewController {
func userDetail() {
    let url = URL(string: getApiUrl)!
    let session = URLSession.shared
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue( "Bearer \(userToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print (error)
        } else if let data = data {
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let responseDatas = try decoder.decode(InstaStory.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.datas = responseDatas.data.tagPost
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        } else {
            print("something went wrong")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}}
```